# Single sign on using only Firebase

Tags: firebase, single-sign-on

I have two domains using the same Firebase backend instance. We are using Firebase Email & Password auth only (we have no backend). Is it possible to allow users to roam between domains without forcing them to login again? One thought is that when a logged in user is redirected to the other domain, we pass the JWT in the URL, then use it to automatically login on the other domain. Would that be workable? Are there any security concerns there?

Comment: did you find a solution for sharing JWT tokens for cross domains with a secure way?

Comment: I didn't. The project I was working on ran out of funding before we got that far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JWT tokens that Firebase generates are specific to that Firebase app, but not specific to any domain. So as long as you use a secure way to pass the token from page to page, you can re-use them.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. I have control over the domains used, so I'm leaning towards `sub1.example.com` and `sub2.example.com`, then passing the JWT between the two by putting it in a cookie with a path of `.example.com`. Does that seem like a secure solution?

Comment: How to sign in the user on the second domain with only the JWT / id token? This answer is over 2 years old but still there seems to be no solution for cross domain login with firebase.

Comment: @JedidiahHurt This may be late, but others may find it useful: A good way to secure the solution you mention is encrypting and decrypting the cookie-stored token on each site where you'll use it, using a shared encryption key that's stored safely on each domain.

Comment: @Frank I understand this will work with web authentication, but is there any solution for mobile authentication

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to give admin access of site B to the functions of site A, so once you are logged in site A, it creates same user on B and signs in using a token on backend, then you are logged in on B as well